# Convert time-series in rows to time-series in column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I would like to convert rows to columns. I tried to use transpose function but if it has a lot of SKUs, it is still difficult to use it.

```
A1: SKU, A2: 565FL21701, A3: 565FL21781, A4,571FL21706.
B1: 3/1, B2: 1, B3: 4, B4: 33
C1: 3/2, C2: 2, C3: 5, C4: 35
```

convert to

```
A1: SKU, A2: 565FL21701, A3: 565FL21701, A4: 565FL21701
B1: Time, B2: 1, B3:2, B3:3
```

...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDgnK.png)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

1. I assume Excel isn't recognizing `3/1` or `3/2` as headers, which appears to be the way you're using them. If so, add an apostrophe `'` prior to each TIME value and then `TRANSPOSE` your data.
2. If that doesn't work, try re-organizing your data using the example below as a guide.

> ```
> SKU         TIME       SALES
> 565FL21701  3/2        1
> 565FL21781  3/2        4
> 571FL21706  3/2        33
> ```

Formatted this way, `TRANSPOSE` should work without issue.

---

Also, if a more **senior user** prefers this **answer** appear as a **comment**, please append my post accordingly as I lack the reputation to do it myself.

Comment: Definitely an answer so far as the op's 'question' could be interpreted.